# How to create a rhomboid in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame2

I want to create a rhomboid like this. I can not do this I found the solution just for the diamond.

[image]

my code:

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 700))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue')
points = [(200, 200), (250, 250), (200, 300), (150, 250)]
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.draw.polygon(screen, BLUE, points)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick()
```

Comment: `points = [(200, 200), (300, 200), (250, 250), (150, 250)]`

Comment: Ok, thanks an can you tell me how to make it bigger. because I tested a lot of combinations and it does not work thank you.

Comment: Just change the coordinates e.g.: `[(200, 200), (400, 200), (350, 250), (150, 250)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that draws a rhomboid with a `with`, `height` and offset:

```py
import pygame as pg

def drawRhomboid(surf, color, x, y, width, height, offset, thickness=0):
    points = [
        (x + offset, y), 
        (x + width + offset, y), 
        (x + width, y + height), 
        (x, y + height)]
    pg.draw.polygon(surf, color, points, thickness)

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 700))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue')

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    drawRhomboid(screen, BLUE, 50, 50, 300, 200, 100, 3)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick()
```

[image]

---

If you want to draw an isometric cube, you just need to calculate the correct points and stick the cube from Rhomboids:

[image]

```py
import pygame, math

def drawCube(surf, center, size, angle):
    v = pygame.math.Vector2(1, 0)
    v.rotate_ip(angle + 45)
    lx = round(v.x * size * math.sqrt(2) / 2)
    ly = round(v.y * size * math.sqrt(2) / 2)
    x, y = center
    s = size/2
    f1 = [(x+lx, y-s+ly//2), (x-ly, y-s+lx//2), (x-lx, y-s-ly//2), (x+ly, y-s-lx//2)]
    pts = [(lx, ly//2), (-ly, lx//2), (-lx, -ly//2), (ly, -lx//2)]
    faces = []
    for i in range(4):
        p0, p1 = pts[i], pts[(i+1) % 4]
        f = [(p0[0]+x, p0[1]+y-s), (p1[0]+x, p1[1]+y-s), (p1[0]+x, p1[1]+y+s), (p0[0]+x, p0[1]+y+s)]
        faces.append(f)
    colors = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue"]
    for face, color in zip(faces, colors):
        if (face[0][1] + face[1][1]) / 2 > y-s:
            pygame.draw.polygon(surf, color, face, 3)
    pygame.draw.polygon(surf, "white", f1, 3)

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

angle = 0
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window_center = window.get_rect().center

    window.fill(0)
    drawCube(window, window_center, 150, angle)
    pygame.display.flip()

    angle += 1

pygame.quit()
exit()
```