# A problem with not seeable cube in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I can not see a cube made from rhombuses. I opened this script after a few months and It is not working. I do not remember that in the past after the last chance, my code id had worked or not. it is a complex script. So sorry for the whole script. I have not any details about the error, because I do not have any type of error message.

[image]

my code:

```py
import pygame as pg
import random
import time
pg.init()

BG_COLOR = pg.Color('black')
WHITE = pg.Color('white')
ORANGE = pg.Color('orange')
BLUE = pg.Color('blue')
RED = pg.Color('red')
PURPLE = pg.Color('purple')
BALL_COOR_X = 240

screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 800))
clock = pg.time.Clock()


bg = pg.image.load("bg.png")


def rhumbus(screen,color,plus):
    point1=(170, 500-plus)
    point2=(350, 500-plus)
    point3=(300, 550-plus)
    point4=(120, 550-plus)
    points=[point1, point2, point3, point4]
    return pg.draw.polygon(screen,color, points)

def colors():
    collist = []
    old_col = None
    for x in range(0,10):
        col = random.choice([RED,ORANGE,RED,BLUE,WHITE])
        if col != old_col:

            collist.append(col)
            old_col = col
        else:
            collist.append(PURPLE)
            old_col = col


    return collist

def cube(collist, plus):
    index = -1
    for x in range(0,10):
        rhumbus(screen,collist[x],plus)
        if ball_coor_y >= 500-plus and ball_coor_y <= 550-plus and BALL_COOR_X >= 120+plus and BALL_COOR_X <= 300+plus:
            index = x
            break
    return index
            
def ball(color,x,y):
    pg.draw.circle(screen, color, (x,y),15,)

def plus(y):
    y = y +1
    return y

def minus(y):
    y = y -1
    return y

def move_rhumbus(plus, keys):
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
        if plus > 0:
            plus -= 5
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
        if plus < 500:
            plus += 5
    if event.type == pg.FINGERDOWN:
        start_x = event.x
    if event.type == pg.FINGERUP:
        if event.x > start_x:
            if plus < 500:
                plus += 5
        else:
            if plus > 0:
                plus -= 5
    return plus


def check_collision(plus, index):
    end = False
    if plus > 0 and plus < 500:
        if colorlist[ballcol] != colorlist[index]:
            end = True 
    return end

def ball_color(colorlist,):
    li = [0,1,2,3,4]
    ballcol = random.choice(li)
    return ballcol



# this is a just a 1 level 


done = False
colorlist = colors()
ballcol = ball_color(colorlist)
ball_coor_y = 300
constant_of_px = 516
end = False
restart = False
plus_x = 0
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    #plus_x = move_rhumbus(plus_x , keys)
    print(f"This is a plus_x {plus_x}")
    index = cube(colorlist, plus_x)
    end = check_collision(plus_x , index)
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    ball(colorlist[ballcol],BALL_COOR_X,ball_coor_y)


    
    # ball movement 
    if ball_coor_y < constant_of_px:
        ball_coor_y = plus(ball_coor_y)
        

    else:

        ball_coor_y = minus(ball_coor_y)
        constant_of_px = 0
        if colorlist[ballcol] != colorlist[index]:
            end = True 

        if ball_coor_y == 300:
            constant_of_px = 516
    
    
    #if end == True:
        #screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
        
    
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

my error is not just I can not see the cube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the background need to be cleared:

```py
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    
    index = cube(colorlist, plus_x)
    end = check_collision(plus_x , index)
    
    ball(colorlist[ballcol],BALL_COOR_X,ball_coor_y)
    
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

To ensure that the ball is always visible on top of the cube draw the ball before updating the display.
And the `clock.tick(60)` call limits the frame rate to 60 FPS to reduce CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

You must clear the background before drawing the cube, but not after drawing the cube:

```py
while not done:
    # handle the events
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        
    # update the objects
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

    # [...]

    
    # clear the display
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    
    # draw the scene
    index = cube(colorlist, plus_x)
    end = check_collision(plus_x , index)
    ball(colorlist[ballcol],BALL_COOR_X,ball_coor_y)

    # update the display 
    pg.display.flip()
    # limit the frames per second 
    clock.tick(60)
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

---

Also the position of all Rhomboids is the same. You need to change
the position in the loop where you draw them. e.g.:

```py
for x in range(0,10):
    rhumbus(screen, collist[x], plus + x * 5)
```

---

However, if you want to create a three-dimensional cube, I suggest you read the answer to the following question:

[How to create a rhomboid in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651474/how-to-create-a-rhomboid-in-pygame/73652102#73652102)

[image: How to create a rhomboid in pygame]